# Limits and sequences. computation

Tags: calculus, limits

Hi i’m really new to maths and in my first year in university. i’m not at all good at maths but i get by. i’m on my last question and i’ve tried all sorts of ways to get an answer to this but i can not get it right. Can anyone help, please i’m desperate.

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} (\ln ( x^2 + x + 1) - \ln( x^2 + 2))$$

Comment: Hello, welcome to MSE. Can you write some of the ways you tried out so we can see where you went wrong?

Comment: lim x→∞ (ln (x^2 + x +1) - ln ( x^2) = lim x→∞ ln ( x^2 + x +1 / x^2) = ln (lim x→∞ x^2 + x +1 / x^2) = ln (2)

Comment: Doughnut, first you lost the $2$ term in your second logarithm. Then, why do you believe $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{x^2+x+1}{x^2}=2$? This is a rational limit with same degree in the numerator and denominator, so the answer should be the ratio of the leading coefficients, that is $\frac{1}{1}=1$.

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$\log(x^2+x+1) - \log(x^2+2) = \log\left(\frac{x^2+x+1}{x^2+2}\right)$$
As
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{x^2+x+1}{x^2+2}\right) = 1$$
we deduce that 
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \log\left(\frac{x^2+x+1}{x^2+2}\right)  = 0.$$